# npm ERR! missing script: build in REACT DEPLOYED IN HEROKU

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm

I'm trying to deploy a project in Heroku with `create-react-app` using Node as my server and MongoDB for my database but I'm getting an error. this is my first to deploy a project with React. I have 2 `package.json` files. One for `create-react-app` the other is for my node server.

What I did was:

1. run the build in React,
2. commit,
3. create a Heroku app using `heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git`
4. I pushed it to Heroku master.

Here are the logs.

```
Counting objects: 203, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (187/187), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 191.40 KiB | 5.80 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 91), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
remote: -----> Configure create-react-app build environment
remote:        Using `NODE_ENV=development`
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Multipack
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Node.js
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=development
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.11.4...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        added 85 packages in 3.391s
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because NODE_ENV is not 'production'
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
remote:        Writing `static.json` to support create-react-app
remote:        Enabling runtime environment variables
remote: npm ERR! missing script: build
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-04T05_56_24_845Z-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to klikie.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/klikie.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/klikie.git
```

this is my **package.json** in create-react-app

```
{
  "name": "klikme",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

this is for my server dep:

```
{
  "name": "klikme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.12",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

I added this in my server too since its in the documentation:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things I notice based on what you shared here. You are not using the `engines` section of your `package.json` file to specify the Node.js version to use on Heroku. It would look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.3.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
```

You will also see the version of `npm` separated out above, Node.js comes bundled with npm, so most of the time you don’t need to specify a separate npm version. However, if you intentionally use a different version of npm locally, you can specify the same version of npm on Heroku.

Lastly, there are Heroku build steps and I do not see that in your main `package.json` file. Keep in mind that what I have written here does not apply to your `create-react-app` `package.json` file because that will be blown away when you deploy to Heroku. `create-react-app` will cease to exist in Heroku.

So for Heroku specific actions you will want to add something like this to your main `package.json` file:

```
"heroku-postbuild":
      "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

In regards to what you added in your server, try writing it this way:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Express will serve up production assets
  // like main.js or main.css
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  // Express will serve up the index.html file if
  // it doesnt recognize the route
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

Also, I am assuming this is in your main `index.js` file and you should also have these two lines of code at the bottom of the file:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: hello sir. thank you for your answer. i also followed you instruction. it building the site but when i open it, it says that 404 not found ngix. my from the client and server is the same.  but regardless right because it will be serve in the build folder?

Comment: i change the `heroku-postbuild` too because itll still look for a build script so i changed it to this. `"build": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`

Comment: @artoo, did you get a successful build to Heroku or did it reject the build? That info would be in your terminal.

Comment: i got a success build but when i got to site it just say 404 not found.

Comment: i recreated my heroku. its saying now not found but not 404. i think because its not serving the static file because the environement is not being change. i tried this locally and it runned. `NODE_ENV=production node server` and it runned.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!! im soooooooo stupid!!!! i forgot to add the start script in the main package!!!!! i swear i thought i added it. omg!!!! its deployed know but my database its not getting the data. any idea? after submiting a score it should redirect and get the data from mongo. heres the link if you want to check it out. https://klikie.herokuapp.com/

Comment: heres my mongo connection.

`const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/klikmeDB';
// Set mongoose to leverage built in JavaScript ES6 Promises
// Connect to the Mongo DB
module.exports = mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect(
  MONGODB_URI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }
);
`

Comment: its working now. i added a addons mLabs. thank you very much sir. appreciate the help. :)